# Tuning in Satellite Channels on Mythbuntu

Tags: mythtv, tv-tuner

I have recently set up a Mythtv system using Mythbuntu. It receives Satellite via a WinTV Nova S2-HD Card which I connected to my Satellite pointing at Astra 28.2E.

I have set up the card in MythTV, configured the EIT and I'm up to the stage of searching for channels. Now, what I want to find out is how to scan for channels such as BBC etc. What frequencies will these be on?

Where I was having issues with were getting all the channels which I could have received on my FTA Box. I hope somebody could help me with this.